# Access database cannot create table with default datetime in migration

Tags: c#, ms-access, entity-framework-core, jet-ef-provider

I have some trouble getting the migrations to create default datetime values for my tables. I am using the EF Core Jet provider and need to use MS Access-MDB-Files.

My Connection string is the following:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=4;User ID=Admin; Data Source=<my-mdb-file.mdb>
```

I want to set the default datetime of an property to the time "15:30".
I tried the following things:

- `entity.Property(e => e.EndTime).HasDefaultValueSql("#01.01.1900 15:30:00#");`
- `entity.Property(e => e.EndTime).HasDefaultValueSql("#01.01.1900 15:30#");`
- `entity.Property(e => e.EndTime).HasDefaultValueSql("#15:30:00#");`
- `entity.Property(e => e.EndTime).HasDefaultValueSql("#15:30#");`
- `entity.Property(e => e.EndTime).HasDefaultValueSql("#01/01/1900 03:30:00#");`
- `entity.Property(e => e.EndTime).HasDefaultValueSql("#01/01/1900 03:30#");`
- `entity.Property(e => e.EndTime).HasDefaultValueSql("#03:30:00#");`
- `entity.Property(e => e.EndTime).HasDefaultValueSql("#03:30#");`
- `entity.Property(e => e.EndTime).HasDefaultValue(new TimeSpan(15,30,0));`
- `entity.Property(e => e.EndTime).HasDefaultValue(new TimeSpan(3,0,0));`

And always get the following error message:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement.

Then I dug into the source code of EntityFrameworkCore.Jet and found in the following comment in the class JetMigrationsSQLGenerator:
`// Jet does not support defaults for hh:mm:ss in create table statement`

But in our old code base we do exactly this with an ADO-Driver (it is an legacy Delphi application).

So I have the following questions:

- Am I wrong with my assertion that this is possible in general?
- Is the behaviour implemented in the EF-Core Jet provider wrong?
- And most importantly: How can I get this working?

**Edit:**
To clarify my steps, I always deleted the Migrations folder after changing the model builder configuration and used the functions `Add-Migration <MigrationName>`and `Update-Database`to test this.

**Edit 2:**
It seems like the comment from the EF Core provider is not totally wrong.
Combined datetimes like `#12.30.1899 03:30:00#` which get created by using TimeSpan are not supported by Access. But if enter the create statement into Access directly and just use the time (`#03:30:00#`) it works. But I cannot get EF Core to create the statement like this.

**Edit 3:**
In the cases where I used the function `HasDefaultValueSql`the reason for the wrong syntax seems to be an bug in the EF Jet Provider. When this function is used the created SQL statement ends with `DEFAULT ('#<value>#'),` the problem with this is that the parenthesis are not accepted. This seems to be a know issue.

**Edit 4:**
There was an issue concerning my applications culture. I changed it and now I can get EF Core to generate DateTimes successfully, but these are missing the time values due to the implementation of the Jet-provider.
So the current situation is as follows:
If I use

- `DateTime` I can indeed call `Update-Database` successfully, but have no time values, only date
- `TimeSpan` the `Update-Database` call fails (I suspect that Access does not like dates with time)
- `HasDefaultValueSql("#03:30:00#")` I also get an exception when calling `UpdateDatabase`

I think that the EF Core Jet Provider is the problem here, but I am not totally convinced.

Comment: You're certainly not wrong on that it's possible. I don't have an EF Core project ready, but try assigning a numeric value. Access expresses dates as whole days + fractions for hours, minutes and seconds, so 15:30 corresponds to 15.5/24 = 0.6458333

Comment: `#12.30.1899 03:30:00#` is not a valid syntax for Access. Try: `#12/30/1899 03:30:00#`.

Comment: @Gustav thank you for pointing that out, the CultureInfo of my application seemed to be the wrong one (but I think the EF Core Jet should not operate on my CultureInfo...). But seemingly the time 03:30:00 can also not be parsed and raises an syntax error exception. If I test this with MsAccess I get the same error messages. But in there using #03:30:00# works atleast.

Comment: @Tobias Please open an issue on our [repository](https://github.com/bubibubi/EntityFrameworkCore.Jet) about it (just copy the markdown from here). I'll take it from there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed a combination of multiple factors, including an issue in the provider which was fixed after a report in the github repository.

Answer (score 0):

The one, I would believe it could be, is:

```
entity.Property(e => e.EndTime).HasDefaultValue(new DateTime(1899, 12, 30, 15, 30, 0));
```

as it should be a *DateTime* value, not a TimeSpan.

But it all comes down to, if the OLEDB driver supports it, which I don't know.

Comment: This works if I change my culture to an invariant but I am still missing the time values in the default. (This is due to the EF Core Jet implementation)

Answer (score 0):

I think the provider might be wrong.

I'm not sure how to apply this to your code, but something to consider/try, if possible: when I add a date I use `ToString()`.

```
...
// ToString() removes the milliseconds which must be done to accomodate Access db.
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MyField", DateTime.Now.ToString()); 
...
```

It's not the same as yours because I'm using `DateTime.Now` but maybe adding it would help??